# Probability of having at least one table with $n$ customers

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability of having a certain result after a stochastic process. This process is as follows:

There is a restaurant and customers enters the restaurant sequentially one after the other. The first customer sits at the first table. Subsequent customers sit at an empty table with probability proportional to $\alpha+k\theta$, and sit at an occupied table $c$ with probability proportional to $n_c-\theta$, where $k$ is the current number of occupied tables and $n_c$ is the number of occupants at table $c$. $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are parameters of this process.

I'm trying to figure out the probability to have at least one table with $n$ occupants after $i$ customers entered the restaurant.